# Error: processing vignette failed with diagnostics: 4 simultaneous processes spawned

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cran, vignette

I am building a vignette for R package mistral (see github.com/clemlaflemme/mistral) and the `devtools::check(cleanup = FALSE)` returns a Warning

```
Error: processing vignette 'mistral-vignette.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
4 simultaneous processes spawned
Execution halted
```

I could not find any help on Google. Actually I do use parallel computing in the vignette, is it not allowed ?

Answer (score 10):

I experienced a similar issue. I got the check to pass if I changed the number of cores from 4 to 2, i.e. in the vignette I set `options(mc.cores=2)`. I couldn't find any clear documentation but I suspect `R CMD check` only allows a maximum of two cores based on an obscure comment in Hadley Wickham's [R Packages Book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/check.html):

> NB: you can’t use unexported functions and you shouldn’t open new graphics devices or use more than two cores. Individual examples shouldn’t take more than 5s.

Comment: It's not well motivated indeed. Just quoting directly your link : "NB: you can’t use unexported functions and you shouldn’t open new graphics devices or use more than two cores. Individual examples shouldn’t take more than 5s."

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this answer to see how you can do this more efficiently:

[R CRAN Check fail when using parallel functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571325/r-cran-check-fail-when-using-parallel-functions)